# I want to check the numbers in the 1st column is equal to 2nd column

Tags: awk

I want to check the numbers in the 1st column is equal to 2nd column, and 1st column should be starting with ABC and ending with DEF and number between these should be matching to 2nd column.

can anyone help me here please.

**My input:**

ABC**12345**DEF    |**12345**    |23132331331|

ABC**95678**DEF    |**45678**    |23132331331|

ABC**87887**DEF    |**86187**    |23132331331|

ABC**89043**DEF    |**89043**    |23132331331|

**Output Should be:**

ABC**12345**DEF    |**12345**    |23132331331|

ABC**89043**DEF    |**89043**    |23132331331|

I'm trying to use the foollowing one, but it's not working.
**awk -F '|' '($1 !~ /ABC+[$2]+DEF/)' WHTFile.txt > QC2Valid.txt**

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your requirement:

```
awk -F'|' '{s=$2;sub(/\s/,"",s)}$1 ~ s' input
ABC12345DEF |12345 |23132331331|
ABC89043DEF |89043 |23132331331|
```

The problems in your codes:

- you cannot concatenate strings in awk by `+`
- you cannot concatenate strings in awk between `/.../`, it is static regex expression
- you should use `~` instead of `!~`, from the requirement you described.
- your column two has empty strings, you should remove them before matching

Comment: Thanks for your info Kent, but the 1st column should be starting with ABC and ending with DEF and number between these should be matching to 2nd column.

Comment: @kris you can easily extend the `$1~s` to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

In the column `|12345 |`, is the trailing space data?  I assume not, based on your proposed output.  In that case, the separator isn't just the pipe character.

To see if $2 is embedded within constants in $1, this will do the trick:

```
$ awk -F '[ |]' '"ABC" $2 "DEF" = $1 { print }'
```